# Crystal Reports - Linking to a Table through different intermediate Tables

Tags: database, crystal-reports

I have a linking issue in Crystal Reports with a database that I can only read from.

I am creating an Invoice Report where I want to Group the items in the Invoice Items Table into their Analysis Categories, which means linking the Invoice Items Table to the Analysis Group Table so I create a Group on the Analysis Group Code field. The issue is that I have to use two different links to get to the Analysis Group Table.

1. Invoice Items [ITEMNO] -> [ITEMNO] Stock [AGROUP] -> [CODE] Analysis Group
2. Invoice Items [ITEMNO] -> [CODE] Sub Group [ANLGROUP] -> [CODE] Analysis Group [CODE]

Most items in the Invoice Items table use the first link route but one type of Item can only use the second link route.

I can create this linking in Database Expert but despite not giving me any error message Crystal Reports only uses one of those links.

I then used route 1 in the main report and created a Subreport in the Group Footer that uses the route 2 only but not only does that ruin the Item order but if there are no Items that use the first link route in the main report then the Subreport is not called.

Unfortunately, Crystal Reports cannot Group By a variable otherwise I would do the linking via a Formula.

Anyone have any bright ideas?

Comment: You should be able to do a Group By using a variable as long as you use a Formula Field to return the variable's value.

Comment: Really?! I cannot see how to do this. When I make a Group I must select a database field, the dropdown doesn't include any of my formulas. The only thing it looks like I can do in a formula is change the order. If you could explain how I can do this like you say that would be great :-)

Comment: When I make a group in the list of database fields I drill-down into Report Fields and it lists all of the database fields used on my report.  At the bottom of this list all of my formula fields are listed as well.  The formula fields all have an "fX" icon next to their names.  If you aren't seeing them in Report Fields, please let me know which version of Crystal Reports you use.  Its possible this isn't supported if you are using an older version.

Comment: You were totally right!! :-)

Comment: I found the Group By formula so that has worked perfectly and solved the order so thank you R. McMillan